# Installing macOS Monterey on external SSD stuck

Tags: macos, startup, ssd, install, monterey

I'm trying to install macOS Monterey on an external SSD. I already did that on three others drives before (a few weeks ago). All of them worked fine and only with this one I have problems.

Everytime I was following this guide: https://www.macworld.com/article/672585/how-to-install-macos-on-an-external-drive.html

Everytime I did it the same like explained in the article.

This time the install was stuck on "14 minutes remaining" for about 3 hours. I tried again, formatted the SSD again, again stuck.

After doing some research I found out that there is a log for the install. On the third try after multiple minutes I opened it and it said that the volume isn't formatted in APFS (agree, I formatted it to Mac OS Extended (Journaled) as explained in the article and how I did it the other three times, which btw. also were Monterey installs).

I did some research what is correct now and finally formatted the SSD again with APFS. Still no luck.

I now switched the Mac I'm trying to install this from the third time. All of them get stuck on whatever format I chose.

I believe the SSD (which I bought just 30 minutes brand new before my first install) is faulty. A new one will arrive today.

But maybe in the meantime somebody has an idea what could go wrong here and what I should do?

Also the installer never gave me any error (only the install log did).

Here is some log of the current install:
I started it at 10:39 and at the time of copying it's 10:50, so already 8 minutes after the last log entry.

"only errors log"

```
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Take com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion with type BackgroundTask for pid 576, id 0x8B87
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUAuthenticationManager: Disabling local authentication requirement
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[48599]: SUOSUShimController: Available MSU updates: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SoftwareUpdate: request for status for unknown product MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion for pid 576, id 0x8B87
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUAuthenticationManager: Disabling local authentication requirement
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SoftwareUpdate: request for status for unknown product MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Could not cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion - no assertion found for pid 576
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: (null)：softwareupdated: Service connection invalidated!
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: (null)：softwareupdated: Service connection invalidated!
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SUScan: Using catalog https://swscan.apple.com/content/catalogs/others/index-12-10.16-10.15-10.14-10.13-10.12-10.11-10.10-10.9-mountainlion-lion-snowleopard-leopard.merged-1.sucatalog.gz
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:46 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: Will load trustcache at path: /Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/CodeResources
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: trustcachectl: Failed to install trustcache: 0xe00002c7
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: Failed to load trust cache with error code: 1
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:47 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:48 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:52 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:53 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:53 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:53 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SUScan: Elapsed scan time = 9.4
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Refreshing available updates from scan
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SUStatisticsManager: Successfully reported statistics for category 5
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Take com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion with type BackgroundTask for pid 576, id 0x8B89
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUAuthenticationManager: Disabling local authentication requirement
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Scan (f=0, d=0) completed 
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: 0 updates found:
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[48599]: External updates: (
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SoftwareUpdate: request for status for unknown product MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[48599]: Controller: Received availableUpdatesChanged notification; new updates: [MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4]; new major updates: [012-06873, 002-79225, 012-22320, 012-08272, 002-77154, 002-65695, 002-57023, 002-42341, 002-23589, 071-78704, 001-68446, 001-51042, 001-36801, 061-26589, 041-91758]
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion for pid 576, id 0x8B89
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[48599]: SUOSUShimController: Armed: 0, with mode: 0, date: (null), updates queued for later: (
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[48599]: External updates: (
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUAuthenticationManager: Disabling local authentication requirement
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[48599]: Controller: Received availableUpdatesChanged notification; new updates: [MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4]; new major updates: [012-06873, 002-79225, 012-22320, 012-08272, 002-77154, 002-65695, 002-57023, 002-42341, 002-23589, 071-78704, 001-68446, 001-51042, 001-36801, 061-26589, 041-91758]
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac com.apple.preferences.softwareupdate.remoteservice[48599]: SUOSUShimController: Armed: 0, with mode: 0, date: (null), updates queued for later: (
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: External updates: (
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: Controller: Received availableUpdatesChanged notification; new updates: [MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4]; new major updates: [012-06873, 002-79225, 012-22320, 012-08272, 002-77154, 002-65695, 002-57023, 002-42341, 002-23589, 071-78704, 001-68446, 001-51042, 001-36801, 061-26589, 041-91758]
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: MSU updates found: (
        "<SUOSUProduct: MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4>"
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SoftwareUpdate: request for status for unknown product MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Could not cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion - no assertion found for pid 576
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUAuthenticationManager: Disabling local authentication requirement
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SoftwareUpdate: request for status for unknown product MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUShimController: Armed: 0, with mode: 0, date: (null), updates queued for later: (
    )
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SoftwareUpdate: request for status for unknown product MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Could not cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion - no assertion found for pid 576
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: (null)：softwareupdated: Service connection invalidated!
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: (null)：softwareupdated: Service connection invalidated!
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: (null)：softwareupdated: Service connection invalidated!
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUShimController: MSU update is not yet downloaded & prepared
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Take com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion with type BackgroundTask for pid 576, id 0x8B8A
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: SUOSUAuthenticationManager: Disabling local authentication requirement
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Adding client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: SoftwareUpdate: request for status for unknown product MSU_UPDATE_21F79_patch_12.4
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: AssertionMgr: Cancel com.apple.softwareupdate.NotifyAgentAssertion-BadgingCountChanged assertion for pid 576, id 0x8B8A
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager[576]: (null)：softwareupdated: Service connection invalidated!
Jul  7 10:39:54 iMac softwareupdated[311]: Removing client SUUpdateServiceClient pid=576, uid=501, installAuth=NO rights=(), transactions=0 (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SoftwareUpdate.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager.app/Contents/MacOS/SoftwareUpdateNotificationManager)
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:01 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:02 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:03 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: osinstallersetupd registered client
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:41:52 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Will need to use bundled in license doc
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Helper tool loaded
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Forcing MSU springboard for target: disk4s2 (Error Domain=com.apple.OSInstallerSetup.error Code=223 "Dieses Volume ist nicht als APFS formatiert." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Dieses Volume ist nicht als APFS formatiert.})
```

To not post the whole log (only if needed) these are the last lines in the "all reports" log:

```
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: ignoreDict
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]:     {
        "com.adobe.switchboard-2.0" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.amazon.Kindle" =     {
            "Maximum Version" = 50157;
        };
        "com.bittorrent.BitTorrent" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divx.DivXConverter" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divx.DivXEngine" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divx.DivXMediaServer" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divx.DivXUpdate" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divx.DivX_Player" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divx.DivX_Preferences" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divx.TransferWizard" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.divxinc.uninstalldivxformac" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.microsoft.Excel" =     {
            "Maximum Version" = "15.24";
            "Minimum Version" = "15.0";
        };
        "com.microsoft.Outlook" =     {
            "Maximum Version" = "15.24";
            "Minimum Version" = "15.0";
        };
        "com.microsoft.Powerpoint" =     {
            "Maximum Version" = "15.24";
            "Minimum Version" = "15.0";
        };
        "com.microsoft.Word" =     {
            "Maximum Version" = "15.24";
            "Minimum Version" = "15.0";
        };
        "com.microsoft.onenote.mac" =     {
            "Maximum Version" = "15.24";
            "Minimum Version" = "15.0";
        };
        "com.riotgames.LeagueofLegends.LeagueClient" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.riotgames.leagueoflegends" =     {
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "org.audacityteam.audacity" =     {
            "Maximum Version" = "2.3.1.0 ";
        };
    }
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: iterating incompatibleAppList
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: _curateIntel32BitDependentApps
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: mappingDict
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]:     {
        "adobe.SpeedGrade" =     {
            "Application Name" = AdobeSpeedgradeKey;
            "Maximum Version" = "10.0";
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.adobe.AdobePremierePro" =     {
            "Group With" = AdobeCreativeSuiteGroupKey;
            "Maximum Version" = "6.2";
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.adobe.Photoshop" =     {
            "Group With" = AdobeCreativeSuiteGroupKey;
            "Maximum Version" = "13.2";
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.adobe.illustrator" =     {
            "Group With" = AdobeCreativeSuiteGroupKey;
            "Maximum Version" = "16.0.4";
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.apple.Aperture" =     {
            "Application Name" = ApertureKey;
            "Maximum Version" = "4.0";
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
        "com.apple.iPhoto" =     {
            "Application Name" = iPhotoKey;
            "Maximum Version" = 1000;
            "Minimum Version" = "0.0";
        };
    }
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: iterating intel64AppList
Jul  7 10:40:05 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: Finished searching for incompatible/32 bit apps
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: JS: 12.3.1
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Failed to get bridge device
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: OSISPredicateUpdateProduct: Incompatible Apps List: Finished evaluating products in catalog (254 installable products)
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: OSISPredicateUpdateProduct: <IAMSUProduct: key=071-47923, name="Compatibility Update for 12.0", evaluated=YES, installable=YES, staged=NO>: Found product: Incompatible Apps List
Jul  7 10:40:08 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Found incompatible apps list on software update catalog
Jul  7 10:41:52 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Will need to use bundled in license doc
Jul  7 10:41:52 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: localizedLicenseURL: file:///Applications/Install%20macOS%20Monterey.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj/License.html
Jul  7 10:42:00 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: IACompatibilityCheckerEngine found no apps to inform about, selected target(/Volumes/macOS Monterey Kamil), current target(/)
Jul  7 10:42:00 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: Failed to check if a disk is FDE.
Jul  7 10:42:00 iMac InstallAssistant[48698]: OSISClient: Using kAuthorizationFlagSheet
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: mountDiskImageWithPath: /Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/SharedSupport/SharedSupport.dmg
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Using product <OSISCollectionInstallProduct: 0x6000033e4340> at distance 10
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Helper tool loaded
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: UI available: yes
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: PostLogoutApply: enabled
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: : 02e4c000 : Failed to create systemVersionDict
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: : 02e4c000 : Failed to get currentInstalledBuild. Assuming clean install
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: : 02e4c000 : Failed to create systemVersionDict
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: : 02e4c000 : Failed to get currentInstalledBuild
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Forcing MSU springboard for target: disk4s2 (Error Domain=com.apple.OSInstallerSetup.error Code=223 "Dieses Volume ist nicht als APFS formatiert." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Dieses Volume ist nicht als APFS formatiert.})
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Verify calculated time estimate: 4.263318 for /Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/SharedSupport/SharedSupport.dmg
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Required package references: (
    )
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Skipping bridgeOS update because the current hardware doesn't support bridgeOS
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Operation queue started
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Getting offset for dmg in pkg: /Applications/Install macOS Monterey.app/Contents/SharedSupport/SharedSupport.dmg
Jul  7 10:42:04 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Verifying SharedSupport.dmg
Jul  7 10:42:59 iMac osishelperd_msu_springboard[48761]: Privileged helper tool loaded.
Jul  7 10:42:59 iMac osishelperd_msu_springboard[48761]: Will not add removal tool because target is not /.
Jul  7 10:42:59 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Using product PKSecureNetEnabledProduct <file:///Volumes/macOS%20Monterey%20Kamil/macOS%20Install%20Data/> at distance 5
Jul  7 10:42:59 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Extracting /Volumes/Shared Support/UpdateBrain.zip -> /Volumes/macOS Monterey Kamil/macOS Install Data/UpdateBrain
Jul  7 10:42:59 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Finished extracting: succeeded
Jul  7 10:42:59 iMac osinstallersetupd[48704]: Extracting /Volumes/Shared Support/com_apple_MobileAsset_MacSoftwareUpdate/590a42b407ee443d05aa8d8aba993f77249dea4a.zip -> /Volumes/macOS Monterey Kamil/macOS Install Data/UpdateBundle
```

**Edit:** New SSD arrived and I could install it fine first try with APFS. No clue what is wrong with the other one or what changed.

Comment: Did you happen to use an enclosure for the SSD based on the RTL9210? That is known to have issues with monterey. Another thing is that the SSD could be failing. Have you checked its smart status on a windows computer?

Comment: I will try that tomorrow on windows. It's a "pre built" SSD, no internal inside a case. One of my first boot SSDs was such a "self built" one and worked. I will update tomorrow.

Comment: Checked smart status, everything looks fine. Maybe just bad luck? But 4-5 times? I will try it again now and see if it will install this time.